# How do you get multiple points on a minecraft scoreboard when you kill someone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For an example, let's say **Player 1** and **Player 2** are fighting, and **Player 1** kills **Player 2**. Now **Player 1** gets 10 coins on a scoreboard.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to check whether their kill count has changed, then add accordingly. You can do this by creating a scoreboard of type `dummy` (we'll call it "oldKills") that you'll compare to your `playerKillCount` score ("newKills"); if oldKills is less than newKills, this means a new kill was landed, and you then add 10 to whatever your points/coins count is.